# How to hide empty 'Content Zone' div in Omega?

Tags: theming

I'm using Omega and I have "Force this zone to be rendered" unchecked in the Content Zone settings, and "Force this region to be rendered" unchecked in the Regions settings.

Any idea what would force this zone to be rendered even if there's no content? The zone is outputting this:

```
<div id="zone-content" class="zone zone-content clearfix container-24">
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you have the debug placeholders blocks activated? 
There is a checkbox "Enable the debugging (placeholder) blocks" in Appereance > subtheme > settings > debugging tab.

The zones are rendered even if empty.
I suggest you try with this option turned off.